# Not able to create runnable jar for eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, terminal, executable-jar

I have created small java application in eclipse. Everything is working fine when I am creating runnable jar from IDE. but somehow I am not able to create it via terminal (fyi I am using Mac).

Following is my project directory structure

```
./bin (Contains all compiled classes)
./lib (Contains all the third party lib I am using lib1.jar,lib2.jr, lib3.jar)
./src (Contains my java class = myProject.java)
manifest.txt (Contains 2 line, first line is Main-Class:myProject and second line is empty)
```

Following is the command that I used for compiling my classes

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp lib/lib1.jar:lib/lib2.jar:lib/lib3.jar src/myProject.java
```

To create jar file I am using following command

```
jar cvfm myProject.jar manifest.txt bin/*.class lib/*.jar
```

When I run this command I am getting invalid header field. Following is complete error message.

```
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:393)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:180)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:50)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:149)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1147)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can anyone point what mistake I am making or whether do I need to some more stuff ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a good reason to use Maven or Ant to build your project for you.

Comment: post your exact failure message "invalid header field" does it say a field name?

Comment: I have added the failure message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) can be of help here.

I think the problem behind the “invalid header field” message is that the value of the header field must begin with whitespace; try `manifest.txt` containing

```
Main-Class: myProject
```

instead.

As for accessing the classes in the `lib/*.jar` files, Java won't find classes inside jar files inside jar files—you can actually skip specifying `lib/*.jar` on the `jar` command line.

Here are two possibilities:

- Add

  ```
  Class-Path: lib/lib1.jar lib/lib2.jar lib/lib3.jar
  ```

  to `manifest.txt`. The disadvantage to this is that if you distribute your jar and the library jars are not at the correct relative paths, there will be a ClassNotFoundError.
- Unzip all the `.class` files from inside `lib/*.jar` into a temporary directory and add them to `myProject.jar`. The advantage to this is that the jar is completely self-contained; the disadvantage is that it is a larger file that is more complicated and takes more time to create. You could use a shell script along these lines:

  ```
  mkdir lib/expanded
  cd lib/expanded
  for J in ../*.jar; do
      unzip "${J}"
      rm -rf META-INF
  done
  zip -R ../../myProject.jar *
  cd .. && rm -rf expanded
  ```

  The `META-INF` directory is deleted after extracting each `lib/*.jar` file so that `unzip` won’t ask whether to overwrite, and so that it doesn’t overwrite the manifest of `myProject.jar`.

Comment: Ok this thing worked out but now I am having issues with nunning that jar. I am using following code to run the jar :java -jar myProject.jar but I am getting classNotFound error

Comment: I edited my answer—I’m not sure if you get notified of that without me adding a comment too.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the jar manfile, I guess you could try something like this:

`jar cvmfe manifest.txt myProjecy.jar myProject bin/*.class lib/*.jar`

Where `myProject` is your entry class name. If that doesn't work, try removing the `-m` option and `manifest.txt` completely, I guess the `-e` option should take of the MainClass entry anyway.